# Adding More Red

Tags: javascript

Here I have to  write a program to make an image have more red in it, by adding a given value to the red, making sure it doesn’t go over 255. The program should have a function called moreRed with two parameters, a pixel and a value to increase the red by. I have to run the program on an image to see it get redder.
I'm not sure how I should go about writing a function for moreRed that will lead to a working program where the value of red is increased or decreased by a certain variable. I think I have it right, just need to have the error message I get be figured out why.

```
function moreRed(pixel, increaseRedByXpixels) {
    var red = pixel.getRed() + increaseRedByXpixels;
    if (red > 255) red = 255; 
    pixel.setRed(red);
    var img = new SimpleImage("pixabayhands.jpg");

    for (var pix in img.values()); {
        moreRed(pix, 80);
        print (img);
    }
}
```

Comment: The function name is not correct... use `function moreRed(pixel, inc...) { } `... Also, are you using canvas?

Comment: I'm not sure what canvas is so no, I think.

Comment: where did you define your "pixel" object that you have your .getRed and .setRed getter/setter methods?

Is there some script that you forgot to include in your question?

Comment: I have not forgotten to add some missing code. Pixel is a parameter in the function moreRed.

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon after your loop condition is the cause of the problem:

```
for(var pix in img.values()); {
----------------------------^
```

Comment: Fixed it but this error message still shows up: Error:
Line 2
pixel.getRed is not a function

Comment: As the other commenters indicate, it seems like you're expecting some other script to provide these functions. Do you have any docs telling you where SimpleImage and the corresponding pixel types are coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the right answer:

```
function moreRed(pixel, increaseRedByXpixels){
var red = pixel.getRed() + increaseRedByXpixels;
if (red > 255){
    red = 255;
}
pixel.setRed(red);
}
var image = new SimpleImage("pixabayhands.jpg");
print(image);
for(var pix of image.values()){
moreRed(pix, 80);
}
print(image);
```

The code above works perfectly, I made a mistake. I wrote 'in' instead of 'of' in my for loop.